# Proxying a private network (Ethernet LAN) at workplace to home via a VPS

Tags: ethernet, lan, isp, proxy

We have a 172.20.0.0/* LAN at workplace. I have a Computer in this LAN with IP 172.20.164.174. This Computer has both Internet connection and workplace network access. I also have a Computer in home with IP 10.0.0.50 from my ISP. It is connected directly to ISP network and has ADSL Internet connection. Also, I have a VPS (Virtual Private Server) which has a public valid IP address. It will be my shared point for my home and workplace PCs talks ;)

Now, I need to proxy my workplace LAN to my home's PC via my workplace's PC and my VPS. I mean I would like to install some services on these three computers which enables me to work at home just like that I'm at workplace. i.e. the workplace network know me as 172.20.164.174 transparently while I'm at home!

I know VPN (e.g. OpenVPN) but I don't have access to any PC at my workplace with public valid IP address as an VPN server. I just have my own VPS on Internet.

Which open source software can help me to achieve this possibility? I searched a lot with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, questions by end users of a network not within their control or of a service provider network are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You should contact your IT department as they may have a solution that will meet your needs. Also, providing your own solution may be in violation of security or other policies, which can result in discipline, dismissal and/or legal action.

Comment: @YLearn, could you move this question to http://superuser.com/questions please? sorry for my off-topic post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use some sort of tunnel here.

Option A would be setting up openVPN on your VPS and then connect both clients (home & work) to it. OpenVPN is quite stable and usually reconnects quickly after an interruption (e.g. ISP initiated an IP change).

Option B would be building an SSH tunnel with the VM acting as some sort of bridge. SSH tunnels work quite well and there are also helpful scripts to automate tunnel building and upkeep. Nevertheless I think I'd choose openVPN.

Comment: Thank you so much.I did not know OpenVPN server can be out of target LAN. I'll try that and let you the results.

Comment: I've done it as WLAN<-->IPTABLES:WPC<-->OPENVPN:VPS<-->HPC (W=work, H=home). thanks again.